# Testing folder hierarchy using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am checking the folder hierarchy on a webpage, depending on the type of user. User1 has a set of permissions which enable him to see the folder structure like this :

```
Main Folder
    - First Child
        -First Grandchild
        -Second Grandchild
    - Second Child
    - Third Child
```

Html code :

```
<div id = 0>
    <div id = 1>
    <table id = 1>
    <tbody>
    <td id="content1" 
    <a id="label1" 
    <span id="treeView_treeNode1_name"  
        Main Folder
    </span></a></td></tbody></table>

            <div id = 2>
            <table id = 2>
            <tbody>
            <td id="content2" 
            <a id="label2" 
            <span id="treeView_treeNode2_name"  
                First Child 
            </span></a></td></tbody></table>

                    <div id = 5>
                    <table id = 5>
                    <tbody>
                    <td id="content5" 
                    <a id="label5" 
                    <span id="treeView_treeNode5_name"  
                        First GrandChild 
                    </span></a></td></tbody></table>
                    </div>

                    <div id = 6>
                    <table id = 6>
                    <tbody>
                    <td id="content6" 
                    <a id="label6" 
                    <span id="treeView_treeNode6_name"  
                        Second GrandChild 
                    </span></a></td></tbody></table>
                    </div>
            </div>


            <div id = 3>
            <table id = 3>
            <tbody>
            <td id="content3" 
            <a id="label3" 
            <span id="treeView_treeNode3_name"  
                Second Child 
            </span></a></td></tbody></table>
            </div>


            <div id = 4>
            <table id = 4>
            <tbody>
            <td id="content4" 
            <a id="label4" 
            <span id="treeView_treeNode4_name"  
                Third Child 
            </span></a></td></tbody></table>
            </div>

    </div> /*End of division 1 */
</div> /* End of division 0 */
```

User2 has a different set of permissions, which enable him to see the folder structure like this :

```
Main Folder
    - First Child
        -First Grandchild
        -Second Grandchild
```

Html code :

```
<div id = 0>
    <div id = 1>
    <table id = 1>
    <tbody>
    <td id="content1" 
    <a id="label1" 
    <span id="treeView_treeNode1_name"  
        Main Folder
    </span></a></td></tbody></table>

            <div id = 2>
            <table id = 2>
            <tbody>
            <td id="content2" 
            <a id="label2" 
            <span id="treeView_treeNode2_name"  
                First Child 
            </span></a></td></tbody></table>

                    <div id = 3>
                    <table id = 3>
                    <tbody>
                    <td id="content3" 
                    <a id="label3" 
                    <span id="treeView_treeNode3_name"  
                        First GrandChild 
                    </span></a></td></tbody></table>
                    </div>

                    <div id = 4>
                    <table id = 4>
                    <tbody>
                    <td id="content4" 
                    <a id="label4" 
                    <span id="treeView_treeNode4_name"  
                        Second GrandChild 
                    </span></a></td></tbody></table>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div> /*End of division 1 */
</div> /*End of division 1 */
```

I am using Java Cucumber tests to run the scenarios.

```
Given I am user'User1'
When I log in
Then I should see "Main Folder"
And I should see "First Child"
And I should see "First Grandchild"
And I should see "Second Grandchild"
And I should see "Second Child"
And I should see "Third Child"


Given I am user 'User2'
When I log in
Then I should see "Main Folder"
And I should see "First Child"
And I should see "First Grandchild"
And I should see "Second Grandchild"
And I should NOT see "Second Child"
And I should NOT see "Third Child"
```

1) Many of the steps will overlap, but i cannot use the same selenium code as the xpath of the children changes as the user changes.
I could use an "if else" statement to take the xpath based on the user, but was wondering if there was another way to go about this ?

2) How can I check to see a folder is NOT present ? I could check for the text in my pagesource and assert it is not present, but was wondering if there was a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you could create a wrapper to handle that structure, I wrote something from top of my head, did not test it:

```
public class FolderHelper {

    final WebElement folder;

    public FolderHelper(WebElement element) {
        folder = element;
        isLoaded()
    }

    public void isLoaded() {
        new WebDriverWait(getDriverFromSomePlace(), 30)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(folder));
    }

    public List<WebElement> getDecendants(){
        return getDecendants(folder);
    }

    public List<WebElement> getDecendants(WebElement element){
        // afaik "/div" should return only first level, if not then look into appropriate xpath 
        return element.findElements(By.xpath("/div"));
    }

    public String getElementText(WebElement element) {
        return element.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it from your code using something like:

```
public void yourMethod(){
    // get your main element:
    WebElement main = driver.findElement(By.id("1"))
    FolderHelper helper;
    try{
        helper = new FolderHelper(main);
    }catch(TimeOutException e){ // or whatever you want to use to determine if main element exists:
        // all hope abandon, main was not found, you probably want to stop here 
    }

    // get first level decendants:
    List<WebElement> firstLevelDecendants = helper.getDecendants();
    // assert here, a la:
    Assert.AreEqual(firstLevelDecendants.size(), 3)

    // do with children your assertions:
    for(WebElement e : firstLevelDecendants){
        if(helper.getElementText(e).equals("First Child ")){
            // ok, this one should have decendants:
            List<WebElement> grandChildren = helper.getDecendants(e);
            Assert.AreEqual(grandChildren.size(), 2)
        }
    }
}
```

I really was unable to test it so it may not work as-is, but it's just to give you an idea how I would solve it.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.